# XML vertical line is not drawn on real devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a list item layout, and this layout is used in a StickyListHeaderListView and contains a vertical separator behind an image. The problem is that the view separator is never drawn on a real device despite being drawn on the preview screen.

Here is the xml layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:minHeight="80dp"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
       tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_date"
    fontPath="@string/font_semi_bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:maxWidth="60dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium"
    android:textColor="#999999"
    tools:text="21\nFeb" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview_date"
    android:minWidth="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_extra_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_extra_small">

    <View
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#999999" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:src="@drawable/test_event_cat_1" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_event_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/container"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:textColor="#999999"
    fontPath="@string/font_medium"
    tools:text="ACS Nights’ Soccer Finale"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_interval"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Small"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview_event_name"
    android:layout_below="@id/textview_event_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:textColor="#999999"
    tools:text="4:00 PM - 6:00 PM"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This code generates a correct layout in the preview window of the Android Studio

[image: Android Studio Preview Output]

But the output on the device does not contain any vertical lines as in the preview

[image: Device output]

I tried putting the vertical line in different parts of the layout but still not shown on a real device. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How do you add a new item to your listView?

Does every item have the layout of the entire xml file?

So one row would use the entire layout.xml file?

**EDIT:**

I'm guessing that, since you have 2 views in your relative layout with the line, the image pushes the line off the screen. 
I took me a while to find some reference material, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9423434/4549834).

> RelativeLayout works the same way, the last image in the relative layout wins.

So you'll have to find a way where either you draw the image on top of the line. Or you can draw a simple line as a drawable and set that as the background of your relativeLayout that contains the image

Comment: I add new items using 
mAdapter.addAll(events);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
- Yes every item have the layout of the entire xml file
- Yes

Comment: Where do you set the layout that is used for every row of the listView?

Comment: in the getView method of the adapter

Answer (score 0):

I changed root from RelativeLayout to a horizontal LinearLayout and after doing the necessary layout changes, the problem is solved now !

I've read [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208037/android-child-view-height-not-match-parent-in-listview-item) that RelativeLayout whose parent is a ListView has problems when assigned with match_parent height.